# Create dose response curve using GRzvalue

Tags: r, scripting

I am trying to plot a dose-response curve, and calculate IC50 or IC90 using the GR (Growth rate) value from the GR calculator, any body has the script or got suggestions? thanks

Comment: Hello Omar! please take a quick look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
For a bigger change of getting a useful answer consider 1) adding (example) data so people can see how the data (input) looks. 2) provide code that you tried so far. So you can get pointers on how to change the code. 3) add an example of your desired graph (output). Just asking for someone to make/give you a script usually doesn't work, since people use their free time to help others with their (coding) problems.